# Why does this code require the Monad constraint?

Tags: haskell

While building a monad stack with monad transformers to write a library, I hit a question about the behavior of it.

The following code won't pass the type checker:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module Foo (FooM, runFooM, foo) where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Reader

newtype FooM m a = FooM { runFooM :: ReaderT Int m a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Int)

foo :: FooM m Int
foo = do
  x <- ask
  return x
```

The error is:

```
$ ghc foo.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Foo              ( foo.hs, foo.o )

foo.hs:12:3:
    No instance for (Monad m) arising from a do statement
    Possible fix:
      add (Monad m) to the context of
        the type signature for foo :: FooM m Int
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: x <- ask
    In the expression:
      do { x <- ask;
           return x }
    In an equation for ‘foo’:
        foo
          = do { x <- ask;
                 return x }
```

The fix is easy as GHC suggests, just adds `Monad` constraint to the `foo` function:

```
foo :: Monad m => FooM m Int
foo = do
  x <- ask
  return x
```

But here, the `foo` function only `ask`s the `FooM` value to give its `Int` value and it is already an (automatically derived) `MonadReader` instance.
So I think `Monad` constraint is not required to `m`.

I guess this relates to the implementation of the monad transformers (I use [mlt==2.2.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl)),
but I cannot figure out the exact reason.
I may miss something obvious though.
Could you explain why this doesn't pass the checker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because the `Monad` instance for `ReaderT` is defined as

```
instance Monad m => Monad (ReaderT r m)
```

i.e. the type `ReaderT r m` is an instance of `Monad` only if the inne r`m` is an instance of `Monad`. That's why you cannot have an unconstrained `m` when using the `Monad` instance of `ReaderT` (which your `FooM` type is using via the deriving mechanism).

Comment: Ah! This is the answer I missed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

[`return`s type](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=return) is `Monad m => a -> m a`, hence the need for the constraint.

Answer (score 5):

By the monad laws, `foo ≡ ask`, which will indeed work without the `Monad` constraint. But if you don't require `Monad`, then GHC can hardly make simplifications based on these laws, can it? Certainly not *before* type checking the code. And what you wrote is syntactic sugar for

```
foo = ask >>= \x -> return x
```

which requires both `(>>=) :: Monad (FooM m) => FooM m Int -> (Int->FooM m Int) -> FooM m Int` and `return :: Monad (FooM m) => Int->FooM m Int`.

Again, the `>>= return` does nothing whatsoever for a correct monad, but for a non-monad it isn't even defined and can thus not just be ignored.